# how can I add the current time to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

hi I'm a student needing assistance  in sql server 2008 trying to get the current time to be added into a table

I've researched and was only able to find how to display the current time

```
create table howto
(
    TimeDifference varchar(20) not null,
    StartTime DateTime,
    EndTime DateTime -- this is the current time 
)
go

declare @Etime datetime
select GETDATE()
set @Etime = getdate()
go
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the "Default value or binding" property of the appropriate column to getdate()

```
alter table howto add constraint EndTimeConstraint default getdate() for EndTime;
```

If you are not going to modify the row EVER AGAIN, you can use make the column of type `timestamp`.